# keyword search in string from mysql using python?

Tags: mysql, string, python-3.x, export-to-csv

I am pulling from a mysql database table using python3.4. I use the csv module to write the rows of data from the database into .CSV format. Now I am trying toros figure out how I can vet the rows of data by keywords that may show up in the fourth column of data (row[3]). I was thinking of using the `re module`as below but I keep getting errors. Is it not possible to search keywords in a field that is string type and to filter those results if they have those keywords? I keep getting an error. Please help

```
import re
import csv

userdate = input('What date do you want to look at?')

query = ("SELECT *FROM sometable WHERE timestamp LIKE %s", userdate)

keywords = 'apples', 'bananas', 'cocoa'



# Execute sql Query
cursor.execute(query)
result = cursor.fetchall()

#Reads a CSV file and return it as a list of rows
def read_csv_file(filename):
    """Reads a CSV file and return it as a list of rows."""

    for row in csv.reader(open(filename)):
        data.append(row)
    return data
f = open(path_in + data_file)
read_it = read_csv_file(path_in + data_file)

with open('file.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
   spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

for row in data:
   match = re.search('keywords, read_it)
   if match:       
        spamwriter.writerow(row)
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Please edit the question to include that information.

Comment: This line should be: `query = ("SELECT *FROM sometable WHERE timestamp LIKE %s", (userdate,))` where the 2nd argument is a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on the regular expressions and used

```
for row in data:
    found_it = row.find(keywords)
    if found_it != -1:
         spamwriter.writerow(row)
```